# Human Detection Using HOG Descriptor

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection, descriptor

I'm new for using HOG detector to detect humans on the road, and I've already write the code and try to run it, but it always have the error on the this line: "hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());" this line, can any one tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
    #include < stdio.h>
    #include < iostream>
    #include < opencv2\opencv.hpp>
    #include < opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include < opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include < opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
    #include <peopledetect.cpp>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        VideoCapture cap(0);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);

        if (!cap.isOpened())
            return -1;

        Mat img;
        namedWindow("opencv", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        HOGDescriptor hog;
        hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

        while (true)
        {
            cap >> img;
            if (img.empty())
                continue;

            vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
            hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, 0, Size(8, 8), Size(32, 32), 1.05, 2);
            size_t i, j;
            for (i = 0; i<found.size(); i++)
            {
                Rect r = found[i];
                for (j = 0; j<found.size(); j++)
                    if (j != i && (r & found[j]) == r)
                        break;
                if (j == found.size())
                    found_filtered.push_back(r);
            }

            for (i = 0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
            {
                Rect r = found_filtered[i];
                r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
                r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
                r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.07);
                r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.8);
                rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
            }

            imshow("opencv", img);
            waitKey(1);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Any error in particular?  System catches fire?  Nasal lawyers?

Comment: it says " exception situation on: 0xC0000005: reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF violation"

Comment: I don't know if there is any further step I need to do, like if the "getDefaultPeopleDetector()" need to be initialize at first or what ?

Comment: `#include <peopledetect.cpp>` ? Really ?

Comment: sorry I just don't know what to do, and I saw that the getDefaultPeopleDetector() is coded by peopledetect.cpp, so I include it...

Comment: No... you include 'h files and compile .cpp as a separate unit.

Comment: remove the include of the .cpp file, what error message do you get then?

Comment: if we're talking about the same [peopledetect.cpp](https://github.com/smart-make/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/peopledetect.cpp), the function you want is not defined there but in a header included there... You probably already have the right header (objdetect.hpp) so just remove the `#include <peopledetect.cpp>` line

Comment: ok, I've removed the cpp file, but the error is still the same

Comment: TL; DR. I think hogs are pretty good at detecting Humans, but I wouldn't put much faith in their descriptive ability.

Comment: This might help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should never include .cpp files in a C++ program. There are .h and .hpp headers for that.

Now, for your particular problem, if we're talking about the same peopledetect.cpp, the function you want is not defined there but in a header included there... You probably already have the right header (objdetect.hpp) so just remove the `#include <peopledetect.cpp>` line

Comment: but after removing the cpp file, the error is still there, is there anything wrong with my input format?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same

Comment: using getDefaultPeopleDetector(), I don't need to train any descriptor at all right ?

Comment: I suppose you already know [this page](http://www.magicandlove.com/blog/2011/08/26/people-detection-in-opencv-again/) since you copied the code there and added some errors. Does the original code work with your setup?

Comment: Well, the only difference is that I use opencv 2.4.13 not 2.3, and the input is a video not from webcam

Comment: In the OpenCV 2.4.13 doc, the class HogDescriptor is located in the `cv::ocl` namespace. Try using `ocl::HogDescriptor` instead.

Comment: Also, you say that the input is not from a Webcam but you create a VideoCapture object with the default camera...  @HenryChen

Comment: sorry I don't quiet get your point, you mean to justify this line: "HOGDescriptor hog;"  to "ocl::HOGDescriptor hog;"  ?